# How to pass multiple values while calling a procedure without using comma

Tags: oracle, update, plsql

I have written a procedure to update the status of a column.
Since there are more than 1000 records it's not easy to pass all values using commas.
I have a list of case_intrl_id's in excel and want to pass all those Ids without using commas.
Is there a way for this?

Below is the procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateCaseStatus(
       p_caseid IN VARCHAR2,
       )
IS
BEGIN

  UPDATE kdd_cases SET status_cd = 'CCLD' where case_intrl_id = p_caseid;  
  
  COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: Load those values into a temporary table that you then reference in your `update` statement. And do not commit inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Then how to commit the updated records?

Comment: Outside the SP, obviously.

Comment: ok, so I need to do it separately, right? Also if I use a temporary table then there is no need to write a procedure.  The update statement will be like UPDATE kdd_cases SET status_cd = 'CCLD' where case_intrl_id = (select case_id for temp_table);

Comment: However, I don't want to use a simple update statement.